# Suppress 3rd party library console output?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I need to call a 3rd party library that happens to spew a bunch of stuff to the console.  The code simply like this...

```
int MyMethod(int a)
{
   int b = ThirdPartyLibrary.Transform(a);  // spews unwanted console output
   return b;
}
```

Is there an easy way to suppress the unwanted console output from ThirdPartyLibrary?  For performance reasons, new processes or threads cannot be used in the solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well you can use `Console.SetOut` to an implementation of `TextWriter` which doesn't write anywhere:

```
Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Null);
```

That will suppress *all* console output though. You could always maintain a reference to the *original* `Console.Out` writer and use that for your own output.

Comment: This does work in most cases.  However, in my case it does not.  The external library creates a COM object and at least 1 other thread - possibly even another process so that is complicating my problem.

Comment: Ah. It would have been nice to have known that originally... if it's creating other processes or writing the the console in ways other than using `Console.WriteLine` etc, that does make things a lot harder...

Comment: Yes - sorry, I didn't realize that was important until trying your suggestion.

Comment: I am having an issue where a dependent Managed C++ assembly is executing C++ library code with `sprintf` and `fprintf` commands.  Issuing `Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Null)` doesn't have any affect.  @jon-skeet any ideas?

Comment: @AaronHudon: Well `sprintf` formats into memory and `fprintf` writes to a file... neither of them automatically writes to stdout. I suggest you ask a new question with more details.

Comment: my bad about the `sprintf`, it is the `fprintf( stdout ... )` that is still being written.  I'll write up a new question

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way to do it (which also usually covers managed C++ applications that you P/Invoke from C# or otherwise):

```
internal class OutputSink : IDisposable
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetStdHandle(int nStdHandle, IntPtr hHandle);

    private readonly TextWriter _oldOut;
    private readonly TextWriter _oldError;
    private readonly IntPtr _oldOutHandle;
    private readonly IntPtr _oldErrorHandle;

    public OutputSink()
    {
        _oldOutHandle = GetStdHandle(-11);
        _oldErrorHandle = GetStdHandle(-12);
        _oldOut = Console.Out;
        _oldError = Console.Error;
        Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Null);
        Console.SetError(TextWriter.Null);
        SetStdHandle(-11, IntPtr.Zero);
        SetStdHandle(-12, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SetStdHandle(-11, _oldOutHandle);
        SetStdHandle(-12, _oldErrorHandle);
        Console.SetOut(_oldOut);
        Console.SetError(_oldError);
    }
}
```

This class can be called as follows:

```
using (new OutputSink())
{
    /* Call 3rd party library here... */
}
```

This will have an impact. Any application logic that tries to use the console from another thread during the time you are `using` the `OutputSink` will not function correctly to write to the standard output, standard error, console output, or console error.

Comment: Looked good, bonus points for disposable logic, but didn't work in my case. I do PInvoke into some native code, but it seems they have different ways to write to my precious console.